# tex4ht leaving equations unchanged

Tags: conversion, html, tex4ht

I'm trying to convert a LaTeX document to a webpage that'll be hosted on a server that's capable of processing and rendering simple TeX equations, but not doing section-level formatting.

So I'm trying to convert the document to HTML using TeX4ht, but leave the equations in the form `$ my-eq-here $` in the resulting HTML to have the server process them and be able to modify them later. Any ideas on how to accomplish this using TeX4ht?

Answer (score 7):

`htlatex` provides support for jsMath [out of the box](http://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn-commands.html#QQ1-9-47):

```
htlatex file "xhtml,jsmath" " -cmozhtf"
```

If you need output for a different engine, `htlatex` offers [fine control](http://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn11.html#QQ1-11-59) on how math is to be output. In the [Q/A](http://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn5.html#QQ1-5-23) section of the manual an example is shown that can be adapted to any use case.

To output the original LaTeX source surrounded by $ signs, create a file `my.cfg` in the same directory as the main `.tex` file with the following contents:

```
\Preamble{html}
\newtoks\eqtoks 
\def\AltMath#1${\eqtoks{$#1$}% 
   \HCode{\the\eqtoks}$}
\Configure{$}{}{}{\expandafter\AltMath}  
\begin{document} 
\EndPreamble
```

Now the command

```
htlatex file 'my'
```

produces a HTML file where the all inline equations are represented as their (equivalent) LaTeX source.

You can use the same switches after `my` as with `html`. Replace `{html}` by `{xhtml}` in `my.cfg` to get XHTML output.

Comment: A spurious space appears in commands that take arguments: If I compile $\mathbb{A}$, $\mathrm{A}$, $\text{A}$ I get $\mathbb {A}$, $\mathrm {A}$, $\text {A}$.  How can I get rid of the extra space?