# tex4ht leaving equations unchanged - including \[...\] and \(...\)

Tags: tex4ht

I want to let tex4ht leave the equations unchanged. Using the tip given at [tex4ht leaving equations unchanged](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27510/tex4ht-leaving-equations-unchanged), it works for `$` and `$$` equations. In the case of `\[...\]` and `\(...\)` equations it does not work.

How do I have to modify the provided `my.cfg`  to work in the case of following document?

```
\documentclass {article}
\begin{document}
\[a*b^3\]
\end{document}
```

`my.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{html}
\newtoks\eqtoks 
\def\AltMath#1${\eqtoks{$#1$}% 
   \HCode{\the\eqtoks}$}
\Configure{$}{}{}{\expandafter\AltMath}  
\begin{document} 
\EndPreamble
```

`\Configure{[]}` seems to take only two arguments.
Using `\Configure{[]}{$}{$}` does not help. This leads to

```
Runaway argument?
a*b^3\] \end {document}
! File ended while scanning use of \AltMath.
```

For a complete test, the following file should work:

```
\documentclass {article}
\begin{document}
\begin{math}
math^3
\end{math}
\begin{displaymath}
math^3
\end{displaymath}
\begin{equation*}
equation*^3
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Do you mean [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27510/8057)? Please refer to it.

Comment: @user946850 Yes, I meant that question. I included a reference in the text.

Comment: If I do this, a command like $\mathbb{A}$ becomes $\mathbb {A}$ (with a spurious space).  Is there any simple reason why this happens and a fix, without me producing a minimal working example?

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the [mentioned answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27510/tex4ht-leaving-equations-unchanged) there is a partial<sup>a, b</sup> solution of the question. The following configurations will accept `\(...\)` and `\[...\]` shorthands solely:

```
\Preamble{html}
    \newtoks\eqtoks
    \def\AltlMath#1\){\eqtoks{\(#1\)}% 
        \HCode{\the\eqtoks}}
    \Configure{()}{\AltlMath}{}
    \def\AltlDisplay#1\]{\eqtoks{\[#1\]}%
        \HCode{\the\eqtoks}}
    \Configure{[]}{\AltlDisplay}{}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

<sup>a</sup> *The TeX shorthand configurations and these LaTeX shorthand configurations will not work together.*

<sup>b</sup> *The environment configurations are missing.*

Comment: Your solution works fine for me, except within (proof-)environments. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: In case someone has the same problem (in proof environments or not): a workaround is to use \begin{equation*}...\end{equation*} instead of \[...\].