# Retain display equation as tex code in tex4ht

Tags: equations, tex4ht, xhtml

I want to retain the equations unchanged (for later usage), i tried with the help of [Tex4ht leaving equations unchanged](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33708/tex4ht-leaving-equations-unchanged-including-and), it is working for inline equations, I need to retain for display equations such as like $$...$$, \begin{equation}/\begin{align}....
how to configure these environment to unchanged.

my MWE is

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  text $a+b$ and \(a+b\alpha\beta\)
  $$a+b$$
  Sample text
  \begin{equation}
  \alpha+\beta
  \end{equation}
  Sample text
  \begin{align}
   &&\alpha+\beta\\
   &&\gamma+\delta
  \end{align}
 Sample text
\end{document}
```

and my cfg file is

```
\Preamble{html}
\newtoks\eqtoks

\def\AltMath#1${\eqtoks{$#1$}% 
\HCode{\the\eqtoks}$}
\Configure{$}{}{}{\expandafter\AltMath}  

\def\AltlMath#1\){\eqtoks{\(#1\)}% 
        \HCode{\the\eqtoks}}
    \Configure{()}{\AltlMath}{}

\def\AltlDisplay#1\]{\eqtoks{\[#1\]}%
        \HCode{\the\eqtoks}}
    \Configure{[]}{\AltlDisplay}{}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

I compiled through the calling command `htlatex filename "sample.cfg"`

**Note:**
When I am using the option `xhtml` in the `htlatex filename "xhtml,sample.cfg"`
the equations are changed to htmlcoding, without using html/xhtml option the equations are unchanged. Why equations are changing to html code when i am using the option xhtml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is based on [MathJax support package](https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht/blob/master/mathjax-latex-4ht.sty) from the [Helpers4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht) bundle:

```
\RequirePackage{verbatim,etoolbox}

\Preamble{xhtml}
\def\AltMathOne#1${\HCode{\detokenize{\(#1\)}}$}
\Configure{$}{}{}{\expandafter\AltMathOne} 
\def\AltlMath#1\){\HCode{\detokenize{\(#1\)}}\)}
\Configure{()}{\AltlMath}{}
\def\AltlDisplay#1\]{\HCode{\detokenize{\[#1\]}}\]}
\Configure{[]}{\AltlDisplay}{}
\def\AltDisplayOne#1#2$${#1\HCode{\detokenize{$$#2$$}}$$}
\Configure{$$}{}{}{\AltDisplayOne}{}{}
\newcommand\VerbMath[1]{%
\ifcsdef{#1}{%
  \renewenvironment{#1}{%
    \NoFonts%
  \Configure{verbatim}{}{} % suppress <br /> tags
    \texttt{\string\begin\{#1\}}\HCode{\Hnewline}% we need to use \texttt to get all characters right
      \verbatim}{\endverbatim\texttt{\string\end\{#1\}}\EndNoFonts}%
}{}%
}
\VerbMath{align}
\VerbMath{equation}
\VerbMath{equation*}

\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

`\detokenize` is used for verbatim output of the basic math commands instead of `\toks` register. It seems to be easier to handle.

For math environments, `\VerbMath` command is introduced. It redefines the environment to print it's content in verbatim and to print `\begin{env name} ... \end{...}` around it. It uses `verbatim` package for that.

This is the result from your code:

```xml
<!--l. 4--><p class="noindent" >text \(a+b\) and \(a+b\alpha \beta \)
                                 $$a+b$$
 Sample text  \begin{equation} 

\alpha+\beta
\end{equation}
Sample text  \begin{align} 

&#x0026;&#x0026;\alpha+\beta\\
&#x0026;&#x0026;\gamma+\delta
\end{align}
Sample text </p>
```

Comment: when i am using the option xhtml in the calling command the equations are converting to HTML format, how to retain this in the xhtml option

Comment: `&` alignment characters are changed to unicode characters in your output, but in my output it is changed to `&amp;` this will give wrong output

Comment: @VenkatesanRamachandiran I use `make4ht` with `-u` option, it requests Unicode output. `@amp;` is correct, isn't it? You can't have `&` character in a `xml` file. What do you mean by `HTML` format?