# TeX4HT Equation unchanged with newcommand or def command

Tags: macros, tex4ht

I would like to convert all the inline-math and display-math should be `LaTeX` format only and not for image. I had referred [tex4ht leaving equations unchanged](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27510/tex4ht-leaving-equations-unchanged) and [tex4ht leaving equations unchanged - including \[...\] and \(...\)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33708/tex4ht-leaving-equations-unchanged-including-and). But author defined macros are not converted to `HTML`.

LaTeX MWO:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\La}{\Lambda}
\def\B{\beta}
\newcommand{\twosilt}{\mbox{\rm 2-silt}}
\begin{document}
In this section, we $\B$ recall some definitions and results. 
Throughout $\alpha+\B$ this section, let ${\La}$ be a finite dimensional algebra. 
\begin{equation*}
\Phi:\Lambda\longrightarrow\twosilt\Lambda,\ \ \ (X,P)\mapsto \Phi(X,P):=P_X\oplus P[1].
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

How do achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not really sure, what you are looking for, purpose of questions and answers you linked to is exactly not to convert macros to html, to be processed with some tool like mathjax. Try this configuration file, with definitions of your macros for mathjax:

```
\usepackage{verbatim}
\Preamble{xhtml}
% Configure for mathjax
\Configure{VERSION}{}
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html>\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">                                           
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: {           
      Macros: {     
        \unexpanded{La : "\\Lambda",
        B: "\\beta", 
        twosilt: "\\textrm{2-silt}",}
      }        
    },        
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"], 
    tex2jax: {       
        \unexpanded{
      inlineMath: [ ['\$','\$'], ["\\\\(","\\\\)"] ],
      displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],}
      processEscapes: true
    }                   
  });                  
</script>   
}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<script type="text/javascript"\Hnewline
src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"\Hnewline
></script>\Hnewline}}

\newtoks\eqtoks 
\def\AltMath#1${\eqtoks{$#1$}% 
   \HCode{\the\eqtoks}$}
\Configure{$}{}{}{\expandafter\AltMath}  
\def\AltlMathI#1\){\eqtoks{\(#1\)}% 
        \HCode{\the\eqtoks}}
\Configure{()}{\AltlMathI}{}
\def\AltlDisplay#1\]{\eqtoks{\[#1\]}%
        \HCode{\the\eqtoks}}
\Configure{[]}{\AltlDisplay}{}
\begin{document} 
\newcommand\VerbMath[1]{%
\renewenvironment{#1}{%
\NoFonts%
\string\begin\{#1\}%
\verbatim}{\endverbatim\string\end\{#1\}\EndNoFonts}%
}


\VerbMath{equation*}
\EndPreamble
```

I combined definitions from "leave equations unchanged", added definitions of your macros for `mathjax` and created new command, `\VerbMath`. You need to use this command for every math environment, like `equation*` in your case. It will leave also math environments unchanged. Name this file `myconfig.cfg`.

I also slightly edited your sample file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\La}{\Lambda}
\def\B{\beta}
\newcommand{\twosilt}{\mbox{\rm 2-silt}}
\begin{document}
In this section, we $\B$ recall some definitions and results. 
Throughout $\alpha+\B$ this section, let ${\La}$ be a finite dimensional algebra. 

\begin{equation*}
\Phi:\Lambda\longrightarrow\twosilt\Lambda,\; (X,P)\mapsto \Phi(X,P):=P_X\oplus P[1].
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I added `fontenc` package in order to correctly convert all characters and replaced `\ \ \`  in your equation with `\;`. I suppose that you wanted bigger space, but `\`  seems to be not supported by mathjax.

Now you can compile your file with:

```
htlatex mwo myconfig
```

you can see the result [here](https://www.kodymirus.cz/samples/balaji/balaji.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help and i have many author defined macros and would like how to do in automatically conversion way instead of manual add in MathJax?

Comment: it would be more difficult, you would need to redefine every macro you use to print its name. adding your macros to mathjax seems much easier. but I would suggest you to switch to mathml with mathjax: you would get best performance.

Comment: Equations is can convert to image and any possible all the inline and display equations should convert to `alt` attribute?

Comment: The config file here sufffers some of the same typos as mentioned [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185791/converting-latex-to-html-but-keeping-equations-as-latex) in the comments, in case michal hasn't updated this answer. (And I'm waiting to see if michal agrees.) Additionally, this one has `\AltlMathiI` instead of `\AltlMathI`.

Comment: @alex.jordan yes, the errors are same, as I just copied the same file between different answers

Comment: @Michal: Any updations for `author defined macros only need to change` and all the remaining `$..$` and `$$...$$` equations are unchanged? or Can i switch to LaTeX 2 mathml Conversion. It's possible again `mathml 2 LaTeX equations conversion`.

Comment: @Balaji just use `htlatex mwo "myconfig,mathml` if you want to try mathml

Comment: @michal: Yes, I have used the same syntax like `htlatex test "els, css, NoFonts, xhtml, mathml"`. How do revert `mathml2latex equations` for getting updated/changed (like author used macros) equations?

Comment: @michal: When using `\verbmath` in the config file all the equation cross-reference are not converted. Could you please advise what i have need to update in the `.cfg` file?

Comment: @Balaji could you please post a mwe as new question?

Comment: @michal: I have posted <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261350/equations-are-unchanged-with-verbatim-package>