# Equations in captions causing compile error while converting LaTeX to HTML

Tags: tex4ht

I can manage to convert LaTeX files into HTML with Tex4ht while keeping equations as they are with the config file provided by @michal.h21 on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185802/52068

But it fails when there is an equation with single dollar sign ($equation$) in caption of the images.

With Error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=30000]
```

MWE:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{F39_B.png} 
\caption{Teleportation: the system consists initially of two entangled electrons (2 and 3) with Alice and Bob, respectively, in the state $\ket{\Upsilon}$ (see text). Alice measures one of the Bell states, shown here as $\ket{\Phi^+}$, for example. She sends this outcome classically to Bob, who then corrects the entangled state, here using the identity operator, to put his electron into the state $\ket{\nearrow}$. }
\label{fig:teleport1}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Not sure if I need to add some other parameters to the config file in order to cover equations in captions or there is something wrong with my LaTeX file.

thanks in advance.

Comment: this compiles fine for me when added to sample file from previous question. The problem is probably somewhere else. Could you make complete document, as small as possible, which fails to compile with this error?

Comment: think I sorted it out, it's the label \label{fig:teleport1} that somehow was causing it