# Leave math content alone with tex4ht for MathJax

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, mathjax

[This question and answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68916/convert-latex-to-mathjax-html) explain how one could use `tex4ht` to convert `tex` to `html` with MathJax reading the math. One (of several) problem(s) I am having is that my document uses `\cancel` from the `cancel` package. Even if I alter my `tex4ht` configuration file so that [the cancel extension](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#cancel) is loaded in the head of the `html` file, it's too late. `htlatex` has already converted things like `\cancel{2}` in the `tex` file into image files and inserted `img` elements for them, instead of converting `\cancel{2}` into some kind of mathml equivalent.

Is there a way to have `htlatex` leave math environments untouched? If the delimiters like `\[`, `\(`, `\begin{align}`, etc., and the commands inside them like `\cancel{2}` were left alone when `htlatex` makes the conversion, then MathJax should process the contents as they are, using their raw LaTeX commands and structure (as long as there aren't too many complications.)

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185802/2891 look at `\VerbMath` command in particular.

Comment: @michal.h21 Thanks! When I have some time later today I will give that a try. And then it looks like this question could be closed as a duplicate. I'll vote to close rather than delete if that turns out to be the case.

Comment: sure, let me know if it works and we can close this question, or post `mwe` and I will modify the cfg file according to your use case

Comment: @michal.h21 In the config file there, is `AltlMathiI` a typo, and should be `AltlMathI`?

Comment: OK, this can be closed as duplicate.