# TeX4ht without converting math formulas

Tags: tex4ht, html, mathjax, mac

Maybe my question is very silly or maybe very trivial, but I can't figure out the solution...

I want to regularly publish parts of Latex documents to a Wordpress where I have the MathJax plugin installed: this plugin can "interpret" Latex math formulas and display the correct fonts using Javascript. Due to this, I can copy directly math formulas in my Wordpress. However, I want the rest of the document (everything but math formulas) converted to HTML so I can past it there...

Is there any way to run **TeX4ht** that translates everything, but **leaving the math formulas as they are** (that is, without generating images of them and linking them to the HTML, for instance)?

I'm using the TexMaker editor in a Mac.

Thanks in advance for your time! :)

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185802/2891