# Getting tex4ht to output all math "unprocessed" between html tags

Tags: math-mode, tex4ht

I would like to use tex4ht to convert a LaTeX document to an electronic book format, but rather than MathJaX or MathML, I want all math-mode code to be dumped into the html output between identifying tags. That is, I would like $\alpha$ to appear in the output as $\alpha$, ( \beta ) as $\beta$,

```
\begin{equation}
   E = mc^2
   \label{eq:Einstein}
 \end{equation}
```

to appear in the html with the appropriate formatting for the equation number, but the mathematical expression to appear between  tags (or some such). In short, I would like tex4ht to take care of formatting into HTML everything in the document *except* the mathematics, which I will handle separately in a script I run on the html output file.

I found the code

```
\def\AltMath#1${\eqtoks{<dollar>$#1$</dollar>}% 
   \HCode{\the\eqtoks}$}
\Configure{$}{}{}{\expandafter\AltMath}
```

which seems to do what I want, and I was able to generalize to handle $$. However, I'm having no luck with `\( \)` and `\[ \]` blocks, or with environments such as equation, equation*, etc. I suspect that if I saw how to do these four, the rest would follow fairly easily.

Comment: that should be exactly what the mathjax config does, isn't it?

Comment: please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185802/2891 which tool do you want to use for math post-processing?