# make4ht - broken cross references

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, make4ht

I am using `make4ht` on the file `Test.tex` containing:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    Testing cross references for equations. 
    \begin{equation}
        e^{\mathrm{i}\pi}+1=0 \label{eq:test equation}
    \end{equation}
    Equation \ref{eq:test equation} is known as Euler's identity.
\end{document}
```

using the command

```
make4ht Test.tex "mathjax"
```

to get the HTML code (excluding the header)

```
<body>
    <!-- l. 6 --><p class='noindent'>Testing cross references for equations. \begin {equation} e^{\mathrm 
    {i}\pi }+1=0 \label {eq:test equation} \end {equation}
    Equation <span class='cmbx-12'>??</span> is known as Euler’s identity. </p> 
</body>
```

Am I missing something obvious I need to do to get the correct equation number instead of the `??`?

Comment: As all math content is passed to MathJax, it is not possible to reference to that easily. Either use MathML using `make4ht Test.tex "mathml,mathjax"`, or try the Lua code from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378359/2891

Comment: I was able to get it to work, kind of, using something similar to the link @michal.h21 posted. I added `\renewcommand\eqref[1]{\NoFonts\HChar{92}eqref\{#1\}\EndNoFonts}` to my `.cfg` file for `make4ht`. It breaks if the label contains an underscore, but works well enough for my needs otherwise.

Comment: If it breaks with underscore, try something like `\renewcommand\eqref[1]{\NoFonts\HChar{92}eqref\{\detokenize{#1}\}\EndNoFonts}` (untested, but it should work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as all equations are referenced using `\eqref{}` (not `(\ref{})`), the following hack, as suggested by @michal.h21 in [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378359/2891), works:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathjax}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\eqref[1]{\NoFonts\HChar{92}eqref\{\detokenize{#1}\}\EndNoFonts}
\EndPreamble
```

Save the above in a configuration file, say `MyConfig.cfg` and run

```
make4ht filename.tex "xhtml,mathjax" --config MyConfig
```