# How do I force `make4ht`/`tex4ht` to output all my mathematics as dvi/svg?

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht

I found that `make4ht`/`tex4ht` uses a combination of unicode + dvi/svg images to represent my document in HTML.

I think it would be much more useful to me if I could choose to have all my mathematics (i.e. anything inside `$`, `$$`, or an `amsmath` environment) be represented by DVI/SVG.

But it is not clear to me if this is something I can make `make4ht` do?

Closely related: [Converting LaTeX to HTML but keeping equations as LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185791/converting-latex-to-html-but-keeping-equations-as-latex/185802#185802)

Comment: I must be missing something, but if you just use mathjax mode in make4ht, then all the math will be rendered as svg automatically by mathjax in HTML? For images, I have my makefiles convert all pdf images to svg automatically before calling make4ht, and so all my non-math images (i.e. graphics) are in svg as well.

Comment: @Nasser I use a lot of macros in my math, which `mathjax` fails to handle. Both `mathjax` and `katex` are next to useless for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Curiously, I wrote a [section on picture math for TeX4ht documentation](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/Howto.html#picture-math) just yesterday.

You can use various [TeX4ht options](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/texfourhtOptions.html#-texht-options1) to request the conversion of additional math environments to pictures. See the various `pic-...` options.

One issue with picture math is the vertical alignment of inline elements. If you use something like `$ a = \sqrt{b^2}$`, the `a` character will be placed higher than the surrounding text. This is a well known issue, but I just found a solution, thanks to this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,pic-m,pic-equation,svg}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\Configure{PicMath}{\setbox0=}
{\Css{img[src="\PictureFile"]{vertical-align:-\fp_eval:n{ \dim_to_fp:n{\dp0}/(\dim_to_fp:n{\ht0}+\dim_to_fp:n{\dp0}) * 100}\%;}}
\box0}{}
{ class="math" }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The `\Preamble{xhtml,pic-m,pic-equation,svg}` requires creation of pictures for inline math and equations, also it requires the `svg` format. Then we use the `PicMath` configuration, which is called for all inline math, to typeset math inside a box first. We can then use this box to measure the correct vertical alignment. The formula I use is this: `box depth / total box height * 100`. The resulting value can be used in CSS. You will get something like this in the CSS file:

```
img[src="sample0x.svg"]{vertical-align:-11.56156598541914%}
```

Here is a sample file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{preview}
\begin{document}

Hello $a=\sqrt{b}$, and other text xyz \(a=\sqrt{b}\)

$$
  a = \frac{a}{b}
$$

\begin{equation}
  a = \frac{a}{b}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Compile using:

```
$ make4ht -c config.cfg sample.tex
```

And this is the rendered page:

[image]

Comment: Whoa! This is precisely what I wanted. Thank you!