# Equations are unchanged with verbatim package

Tags: tex4ht

I have maintaining display equations as it is. But the equation cross-link is not converting. How do achive this? My Sample LaTeX file is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
\alpha + \beta = \gamma
\end{equation}
This is the equation cross ref link Eq.~\ref{eq1}
\end{document}
```

My `CFG` is:

```
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\Preamble{xhtml}
% Configure for mathjax
\Configure{VERSION}{}
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html>\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">                                           
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: {           
      Macros: {     
        \unexpanded{La : "\\Lambda",
        B: "\\beta", 
        twosilt: "\\textrm{2-silt}",}
      }        
    },        
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"], 
    tex2jax: {       
        \unexpanded{
      inlineMath: [ ['\$','\$'], ["\\\\(","\\\\)"] ],
      displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],}
      processEscapes: true
    }                   
  });                  
</script>   
}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<script type="text/javascript"\Hnewline
src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"\Hnewline
></script>\Hnewline}}

\newtoks\eqtoks 
\def\AltMath#1${\eqtoks{$#1$}% 
   \HCode{\the\eqtoks}$}
\Configure{$}{}{}{\expandafter\AltMath}  
\def\AltlMathI#1\){\eqtoks{\(#1\)}% 
        \HCode{\the\eqtoks}}
\Configure{()}{\AltlMathI}{}
\def\AltlDisplay#1\]{\eqtoks{\[#1\]}%
        \HCode{\the\eqtoks}}
\Configure{[]}{\AltlDisplay}{}
\begin{document} 
\newcommand\VerbMath[1]{%
\renewenvironment{#1}{%
\NoFonts%
\string\begin\{#1\}%
\verbatim}{\endverbatim\string\end\{#1\}\EndNoFonts}%
}
\VerbMath{equation}
\VerbMath{cases}
\VerbMath{array}
\VerbMath{matrix}
\VerbMath{pmatrix}
\VerbMath{eqnarray}
\VerbMath{eqnarray*}
\EndPreamble
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `mathjax` also for process `\ref` commands pointing to equations (not for ones pointing to sections or figures, which are still handled by LaTeX). As everything in math is handled by `mathjax`, a easiest solution is to use `$\ref{label}$`:

```
This is the equation cross ref link Eq.~$\ref{eq1}$
```

The second problem is that equation is unnumbered by default, so you can't get the reference number:

[image]

this can be solved with following code inserted in `TeX` section in `mathjax` configuration:

```
equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" }
```

full config file with updated `mathjax` configuration:

```
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\Preamble{xhtml}
% Configure for mathjax
\Configure{VERSION}{}
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html>\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">                                           
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: {           
      Macros: {     
        \unexpanded{La : "\\Lambda",
        B: "\\beta", 
        twosilt: "\\textrm{2-silt}",}
      },
      equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" } 
    },        
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"], 
    tex2jax: {       
        \unexpanded{
      inlineMath: [ ['\$','\$'], ["\\\\(","\\\\)"] ],
      displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],}
      processEscapes: true
    }                   
  });                  
</script>   
}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<script type="text/javascript"\Hnewline
src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"\Hnewline
></script>\Hnewline}}

\newtoks\eqtoks 
\def\AltMath#1${\eqtoks{$#1$}% 
   \HCode{\the\eqtoks}$}
\Configure{$}{}{}{\expandafter\AltMath}  
\def\AltlMathI#1\){\eqtoks{\(#1\)}% 
        \HCode{\the\eqtoks}}
\Configure{()}{\AltlMathI}{}
\def\AltlDisplay#1\]{\eqtoks{\[#1\]}%
        \HCode{\the\eqtoks}}
\Configure{[]}{\AltlDisplay}{}
\begin{document} 
\newcommand\VerbMath[1]{%
\renewenvironment{#1}{%
\NoFonts%
\string\begin\{#1\}%
\verbatim}{\endverbatim\string\end\{#1\}\EndNoFonts}%
}
\VerbMath{equation}
\VerbMath{cases}
\VerbMath{array}
\VerbMath{matrix}
\VerbMath{pmatrix}
\VerbMath{eqnarray}
\VerbMath{eqnarray*}
\EndPreamble
```

the result is now much better:

[image]

Comment: I have added `equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" }` in my `.cfg` file and still getting `??`. How do solve this. And also tried `$\ref{label}$` but result is same (`??`).

Comment: @Balaji I've added full config file

Comment: Now it's working fine. But i would like to get `Eq 1` result in the HTML file instead of 1$\ref{eq1}$`.  In Figure cross-link `htlatex` is converting. But in the Equation only is not converting.

Comment: @Balaji equation numbers are added by mathjax, it is not possible to get them from LaTeX.

Comment: But when i have converting all the equaions to `MathML` citation equations numbers (like `\ref{eq1}`) it's generating auto number. This concept is not possible in `LaTeX Equations`? Please check and advise.